# Add filter post_where and passing post_type argument

Tags: wp-query, search, location-search

Following [this tutorial](http://biostall.com/performing-a-radial-search-with-wp_query-in-wordpress/), I want to search for posts within the radius where the `post_type=profile`

```
add_filter('posts_where', 'location_posts_where', 10);
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'profile' ) );  
remove_filter('posts_where', 'location_posts_where', 10);


function location_posts_where( $where )  
{  
    global $wpdb;  

    $latitude = filter_input( INPUT_GET, "latitude", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $longitude = filter_input( INPUT_GET, "longitude", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

    // Specify the co-ordinates that will form  
    // the centre of our search  
    //$latitude = '-27.922459';  
    //$longitude = '153.334793'; 

    $radius = '125'; // (in miles)  

   if (is_search() && get_search_query())
    // Append our radius calculation to the WHERE  
    $where .= " AND $wpdb->posts.ID IN (SELECT post_id FROM lat_lng_post WHERE 
         ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(" . $latitude . ") ) 
                        * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
                        * cos( radians( lng ) 
                        - radians(" . $longitude . ") ) 
                        + sin( radians(" . $latitude . ") ) 
                        * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) <= " . $radius . ")";  


    // Return the updated WHERE part of the query  
    return $where;  
}
```

But it displays no posts and when I debug, this is the SQL query it is actually running:

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) AND wp_posts.ID IN (SELECT post_id FROM lat_lng_post WHERE 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(-27.922459) ) 
* cos( radians( lat ) ) 
* cos( radians( lng ) 
- radians(153.334793) ) 
+ sin( radians(-27.922459) ) 
* sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) <= 125) ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

This line is the problem: `AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'` Why isn't the WP_Query argument working to pass `post_type = profile`? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this part from your `posts_where` filter:

```
if (is_search() && get_search_query())
```

Note that `is_search()` is a check on the main query.

If you want to target the main search query, there's the `posts_search` filter available.

**Important**: Watch out for possible SQL injections, as you are taking user input into the SQL query. I think the `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` filter is too weak here, as it allows e.g. parentheses, where it allows the user to modify the structure of the SQL query. Consider `$wpdb->prepare()` with `%f`or `%F` [type specifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) for floating point numbers.

Comment: ps: I've played a little bit with *geo query* support in `WP_Query` [here](https://github.com/birgire/geo-query).

Comment: I removed `is_search` part from the function and it did work. Using the debug bar, I could see that the correct SQL Query with the correct post_type has been executed. However, the page still displays no posts. I'm at my wits end.

Comment: Thanks for the extra tip about SQL injections. I will modify the query to implement that.

Comment: How would I use `$wpdb->prepare` with `posts_where`?

Comment: thanks for your answer! It worked finally although it doesn't display any posts yet. I know this because I did a var dump on WP_Query and it is returning with the expected results. Now I just need to check why `if(have_posts())` is returning false.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that if you want to loop a secondary query you have to use e.g. `if( $query->have_posts() )`  etc. as `if( have_posts() )` is only for the main query loop.  @input

Comment: and the while part: `while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post(); ... `etc If that's still gives a problem, then it might be worthwhile to ask a new question showing the loop code you tried. Best of luck @input

Answer (score 1):

You are removing the filter too early. Remove it after you have completed your loop and everything should be fine. Simply building a new WP_Query object doesn't actually apply the filters on instantiation. The filters are applied in the `get_posts()` method of the query object.

Comment: If I comment out the `remove_filter` part, it still doesn't show up any results and debug shows the same SQL query.

Comment: Where are you trying to use this query @input?

Comment: The `get_posts()` method is actually called when a `WP_Query` object is constructed with non-empty input arguments.

Comment: @birgire Ahh I just looked at that and you're right. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @BrianFegter, in `functions.php`